# Как преобразовать дату из строки в число! JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, парсер, время, сравнение

Помогите решить как оказалось сложную для меня задачу.
На странице динамические формируется блок div c span внутри которые содержат текст. Текст - это время в формате **пример: 1 ч. 10 мин.** На формат я ни как не могу повлиять так как получаю его с другого сервиса. Задача получить общее время из всех что есть в списке, а там может быть разное кол-во.
Сам блок я перебираю на элементы и получаю это время, но что делать дальше уже просто не знаю. Уже перебрал множество методов, но всё тщетно.  Может кто знает ответ или просто натолкните на мысль.

Пример кода:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var elem = $("[data-time-f='dtm']");

  $(elem).each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dtm-time">
    <span data-time-f="dtm">1 ч. 10 мин.</span>
    <span data-time-f="dtm">20 мин.</span>
    <span data-time-f="dtm">30 мин.</span>
    <span data-time-f="dtm">1 ч 23 мин.</span>
    <span data-time-f="dtm">3 ч 42 мин.</span>
    <span data-time-f="dtm">17 мин.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: А данные, которые вы получаете с другого сервиса можете привести, чтобы было понятно, можно ли использовать их из переменной, а не парсить форму

Comment: Нет. Они передаются только в span и я ни как не могу влиять на их формат, внешний вид и т.д. Динамически формируются на странице!

Answer (score 2):

В totalMinute будет общее к-во минут. Думаю трудностей с переводом в строку не возникнет ;)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        function getMinuteTime(time) {
            var hour = time.match(/(\d+)\sч/);
            var minute = time.match(/(\d+)\sм/);
            return (hour && hour[1] | 0) * 60 + (minute && minute[1] | 0);
        }

        var elem = $("[data-time-f='dtm']");
        var totalMinute = 0;
        $(elem).each(function () {
            totalMinute += getMinuteTime($(this).text());
        });

    });
```

Comment: Я вам чрезмерно благодарен. Огромное спасибо за решение!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы парсил строку и разбивал ее по кусочкам а из кусочков потом собирал дату, нпример

```
str='1 ч. 10 мин.'
arr = str.split('ч');
hour=arr[0]; // тут у нас часы, рекомендую очистить на всякий случай от всякого мусора
minutes=arr[1]; // а тут останутся минуты, тоже очистить от ненужного
```

на тот случай если в строке нет часов, можно ввести прсотенькое условие, чтонибудь вроде

```
 var re = '/ч/gi'; // игнорируем регистр и ищем по всей строке
    var str = ' 10 мин.';
   if(str.replace(re, '')){
// часы есть в строке тогда бьем строка как написано выше если не то строка уже минуты и значит ее нужно лишь очистить от мусора
}
```

Comment: Вот думал о похожем, но не совсем понимал как реализовать. Спасибо натолкнули на мысль!